# How can I simultaneously transform the attribute and content of a node?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am converting an XML document to HTML, and am struggling to select both the attribute and content of the original element.

The XML document contains variables (inserted by the document editor) like this example:

```
<var styleclass="Interface b">&lt;%BACKGROUND%&gt;</var>
```

I would like to both convert the text content and surround this with a `span` tag to apply the style.

My XSLT declarations are as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="var">
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="@style='font-weight:bold;'">
            <strong>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </strong>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@styleclass='Interface'">
            <span style="color:white; background-color: rgb(98, 98, 98);">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </span>
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="@styleclass='Interface b'">
            <span style="color: rgb(98, 98, 98); background-color: rgb(233, 180, 0);">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>         
        <xsl:when test="@styleclass='Interface c'">
            <span style="color: black; background-color: rgb(234, 235, 237);">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </span>
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="@styleclass='Warning a'">
            <span style="color:#e74c3c">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>         
        <xsl:otherwise> 
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="var[contains(text(),'BACKGROUND')]">
    Background
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="var[contains(text(),'COLOR PICKER')]">
    Color picker
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="var[contains(text(),'PARAGRAPH')]">
    Paragraph
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="var[contains(text(),'IMPORT DATA')]">
    Import data
</xsl:template>
```

However, the output contains the correctly converted text but without the surrounding `span` tag.

Comment: Are you really tied to XSLT 1.0? It might be a good use case of `xsl:next-match` in XSLT 2 and 3 (which has good support on various platforms due to SaxonJS 2 or Saxon 10/11 being available for .NET, Java, C/C++, Python).

Comment: I am using oXygen XML editor so I should be able to transition to these versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XSLT 2/3 I would consider using `xsl:next-match` e.g. along the lines of

```
  <xsl:template match="var[contains(.,'BACKGROUND')]">
    Background
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="var[@styleclass = 'Interface b']">
    <span style="color:white; background-color: rgb(98, 98, 98);">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </span>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" on-multiple-match="use-last"/>
```

So for the attribute based match I have also used a template with the particular condition in a predicate and would suggest to write a new template for each new condition instead of those `xsl:choose/xsl:when` approach.

But even if you prefer that you can use `xsl:next-match` in there instead of `xsl:apply-templates`.

Comment: And in 1.0, in place of `xsl:next-match`, you could use `xsl:apply-templates` with a specific mode.

Comment: That has worked well, Martin. I am very grateful.

Comment: I actually thought that XSLT moved on by default to the next match, so I would be interested to understand the logic underlying `xsl:next-match` if you have the time.

Comment: @TMiles, can you try reading https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#apply-imports first? Or is that too complicated?

Comment: That is a very good resource, which I have bookmarked.